# Is there a way to compose reified lenses?

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens

I was trying to use the lens library to solve the following problem:

Given the list version of a tree, make a tree.
Example:

```
Given:
  [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]

I should make a tree:
     1
   2   3
  4 5 6 7
```

My solution was to create nodes according to depth using the state monad and
lenses.

My tree data type:

```
data Tree a = Nil | Node a (Tree a) (Tree a) deriving (Show)
```

A stringy version of what I was going for, for calculating the lenses:

```
calculateSetters 1 = ["_Node . _2", "_Node . _3"]
calculateSetters n = (++) <$> calculateSetters (n-1) <*> [ "_Node . _2", "_Node . _3" ]

-- where "_Node" is a prism and "_2" and "_3" are lenses
```

The non-stringy version would output all the lenses to the empty children at a
given depth which I could just set using `.~`. The gist of the non-stringy version looked something like:

```
calculateSetters n = Setter <$> combinations where
  combinations = (.) <$> calculateSetters (n-1) <*> [ _Node . _2, _Node . _3 ]
```

Two problems I ran into

1. I apparently can't map reifier constructors (
   `fmap Setter [ _1, _1]` is an error but `[Setter _1, Setter _1]` is not).  I
   read it was probably because the lenses are polymorphic and end up binding to
   something conrete unless I reify them immediately.
2. I can't make a reified lens `[Setter _1]` and then somehow combine it with
   another reified lens `[Setter _2]` to get `[Setter $ _1 . _2]`.  It seems like
   you can for one-offs in ghci: `:t Setter $ runSetter (Setter _2) . runSetter (Setter _2)` seems to typecheck but I can't work with lists.

I ended up just hardcoding a couple like so:

```
calculateSetters :: Int -> [ReifiedSetter (Tree Int) (Tree Int) (Tree Int) (Tree Int)]
calculateSetters 1 =
  [ Setter $ _Node . _2,
    Setter $ _Node . _3
  ]
calculateSetters 2 =
  [ Setter $ _Node . _2 . _Node . _2,
    Setter $ _Node . _2 . _Node . _3,
    Setter $ _Node . _3 . _Node . _2,
    Setter $ _Node . _3 . _Node . _3
  ]
calculateSetters 3 =
  [ Setter $ _Node . _2 . _Node . _2 . _Node . _2,
    Setter $ _Node . _2 . _Node . _2 . _Node . _3,
    Setter $ _Node . _2 . _Node . _3 . _Node . _2,
    Setter $ _Node . _2 . _Node . _3 . _Node . _3,
    Setter $ _Node . _3 . _Node . _2 . _Node . _2,
    Setter $ _Node . _3 . _Node . _2 . _Node . _3,
    Setter $ _Node . _3 . _Node . _3 . _Node . _2,
    Setter $ _Node . _3 . _Node . _3 . _Node . _3
  ]
calculateSetters 4 =
  [ Setter $ _Node . _2 . _Node . _2 . _Node . _2 . _Node . _2,
    Setter $ _Node . _2 . _Node . _2 . _Node . _2 . _Node . _3,
    Setter $ _Node . _2 . _Node . _2 . _Node . _3 . _Node . _2,
    Setter $ _Node . _2 . _Node . _2 . _Node . _3 . _Node . _3,
    Setter $ _Node . _2 . _Node . _3 . _Node . _2 . _Node . _2,
    Setter $ _Node . _2 . _Node . _3 . _Node . _2 . _Node . _3,
    Setter $ _Node . _2 . _Node . _3 . _Node . _3 . _Node . _2,
    Setter $ _Node . _2 . _Node . _3 . _Node . _3 . _Node . _3,
    Setter $ _Node . _3 . _Node . _2 . _Node . _2 . _Node . _2,
    Setter $ _Node . _3 . _Node . _2 . _Node . _2 . _Node . _3,
    Setter $ _Node . _3 . _Node . _2 . _Node . _3 . _Node . _2,
    Setter $ _Node . _3 . _Node . _2 . _Node . _3 . _Node . _3,
    Setter $ _Node . _3 . _Node . _3 . _Node . _2 . _Node . _2,
    Setter $ _Node . _3 . _Node . _3 . _Node . _2 . _Node . _3,
    Setter $ _Node . _3 . _Node . _3 . _Node . _3 . _Node . _2,
    Setter $ _Node . _3 . _Node . _3 . _Node . _3 . _Node . _3
  ]
calculateSetters _ = error "unsupported; too lazy"
```

which works but I was wondering if and how I can do this programatically?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can certainly compose reified setters, though I'm not aware of a standard function that does this. But it can be done in the obvious way:

```
composeSetters :: ReifiedSetter' a b -> ReifiedSetter' b c -> ReifiedSetter' a c
composeSetters (Setter f) (Setter g) = Setter (f . g)
```

Then, everything else can be done using only reified setters and therefore no impredicative problems:

```
calculateSetters :: Int -> [ReifiedSetter' (Tree Int) (Tree Int)]
calculateSetters 1 =
  [ Setter (_Node . _2)
  , Setter (_Node . _3)
  ]
calculateSetters n
     = composeSetters <$> calculateSetters (n-1) <*> calculateSetters 1
```

Compilable version:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes      #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}

import Control.Lens

data Tree a = Nil
            | Node { _nodeValue :: a
                   , _lSubtree :: Tree a
                   , _rSubtree :: Tree a
                   }
  deriving (Show)

makeLenses ''Tree

composeSetters :: ReifiedSetter' a b -> ReifiedSetter' b c
                        -> ReifiedSetter' a c
composeSetters (Setter f) (Setter g) = Setter (f . g)

subtreeSetters :: [[ReifiedSetter' (Tree Int) (Tree Int)]]
subtreeSetters
   = [Setter id]
   : [ composeSetters <$> strs <*> [Setter lSubtree, Setter rSubtree]
     | strs <- subtreeSetters ]
```